# Regular dropdown and mega menu in the same navbar - is this possible?

Tags: css

I haven't seen instructions for this anywhere - but I managed to put regular dropdown and mega menu in the same navbar. However, if the drop down menus are on the right side of the megamenu, it doesn't work (the dropdown menu items are not visible), But if the dropdown menus are on the left of the megamenu button, then everything works.

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Hello! Welcome! I think you may have more luck with this question on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ . It might help to include some diagrams and/or examples as well.

Comment: What do you mean by mega menu?